# Help with Baby Rudin Theorem 11.8

Tags: real-analysis

[image: text]
[image: text]

${\scr E}$ is the family of all elementary subsets of $R^p$.
Hello everyone! For the proof of theorem 11.8 part $(a)$, I don't understand the last second line. That is,
$$
\mu(A)\leq \mu(F)+\epsilon \leq \mu\left(A_1\bigcup\cdots\bigcup A_N\right)+\epsilon\leq \sum_{1}^N \mu(A_n)+\epsilon \leq \mu^*(A)+2\epsilon.
$$
Could you please explain the last three inequalities in details?
Here is the definition for the outer measure $\mu^*$:
[image: text]

Comment: I realized that the second inequality is followed by the nonnegative and additive properties of $\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality is $\mu(F)\geq\mu(A)-\varepsilon$. The second one is that if $X\subset Y$, then $\mu(X)\leq\mu(Y)$ (here, $X=F$, $Y=A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_N$). The third one is the subadditivity of $\mu$. And the last one is $\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(A_n)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)\leq\mu^*(A)+\varepsilon$, this latter inequality was established before.

Comment: I think Rudin didn't show the subadditivity of $\mu$ in previous contents. Actually I don't understand why we have $\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(A_n)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$. The right hand side is $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n$, where $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i)$. How to show $\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(A_n)$ is less than or equal to the limit of partial sums?

Comment: Because $\{s_n\}$ is an increasing sequence.

Comment: $s_n\geq s_N$ for $n\geq N$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n \geq s_N$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yep. $\!\!\!\!$