# On theorem 11.8 Rudin Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804629/help-with-baby-rudin-theorem-11-8) is a copy of theorem 11.8 Rudin Analysis. How the inequality just after (20) holds?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)\leq\mu^*(A)+\varepsilon$$

I checked every previous definitions and equations but I can't derive the mentioned inequality.

My second question is Rudin has defined subaddivity for $\mu*$ not $\mu$, so how the *third* inequality in $\mu(A)\leq \mu(F)+\epsilon \leq \mu\left(A_1\bigcup\cdots\bigcup A_N\right)+\epsilon\leq \sum_{1}^N \mu(A_n)+\epsilon \leq \mu^*(A)+2\epsilon$ holds?

Please help!

Comment: If this is (20) it said true for all $\epsilon >0$ so let $\epsilon=1/n$ and make $n$ arbitrarily large. Then inequality holds with $\epsilon=0.$ [That's a standard result provable by contradiction.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**Definition 11.7** provides the answer you're looking for: since $\mu^*(E)$ is the greatest lower bound of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu\left(A_{n}\right)$ over all possible families of open elementary sets $\{A_n\}$ covering $E$, for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can find one such family such that your inequality holds.

As for your second question, that inequality holds because the collection of sets $\{A_n\}$ is finite and the measure $\mu$ is finitely additive: see equations (6) and (11) in that chapter.

Comment: @L.G. just edited.

Comment: @L.G. sorry, my mistake. Edited again.

Comment: Thanks a ton :)